# Symfony messenger install for mailer: PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amqp.so'

Tags: symfony, crash, amqp, messenger, mailer

When I run composer require `symfony/mailer`
I have this screen:

> If you want to send emails asynchronously:
> 1. Install the messenger component by running composer require messenger;
> 2. Add 'Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage': amqp to the
> config/packages/messenger.yaml file under framework.messenger.routing
> and replace amqp with your transport name of choice.

I run `composer require messenger`

My `config/packages/messenger.yaml`:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        failure_transport: failed

        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            async:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                    use_notify: true
                    check_delayed_interval: 60000
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 3
                    multiplier: 2
            failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            # sync: 'sync://'

        routing:
            #Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async
            Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: amqp
            Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\ChatMessage: async
            Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage: async
            # Route your messages to the transports
            #'App\Message\YourMessage': async
```

I have now :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amqp.so'
> (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/amqp.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/amqp.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
> /usr/lib/php/20200930/amqp.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/amqp.so.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

I tried to install `amqp` library and I can't use `phpize`,
I tried to install `php-dev` and many others, it crashed in all...

Answer (score 0):

I ran sudo apt install php8.1-amqp
and add new error

```
--show-private options doesn't exist
```

It be a Bug for VSCode that I 've resolved by change --show-private by --show-hidden in ~/.vscode/extensions/thenouillet.symfony-vscode-1.0.2/out/symfony/provider/ConsoleContainerProvider.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't have error in the VSCode console but I have this one in my deBug Bar of Symfony:

```
Invalid Messenger routing configuration: the "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage" class is being routed to a sender called "amqp". This is not a valid transport or service id.
```

Comment: A lot of bugs for one person no ?